# Cannot authenticate R Studio Server with pam_pwdfile

Tags: r, authentication, pam, rstudio-server

RStudio Server authentication with libpam-pwdfile
I'm developing a Vagrant box with a full analytic stackand this includes, ofc, a RStudio Server instance.

I decided to use this pam module https://github.com/tiwe-de/libpam-pwdfile as it allows to authenticate against a pwd file. This allows me to let users access to RStudio without the need to make them server users.

But I'm not able to authenticate at all!

I've added these two files to my setup:

1. /etc/rstudio/passwd

`jdoe:s/NKv5DK33kxQ`

(the password was made using mkpasswd using crypt)

2. /etc/pam.d/rstudio

   `auth required pam_pwdfile.so pwdfile=/etc/rstudio/passwd
   account required pam_permit.so
   session required pam_permit.so
   password required pam_deny.so`

When I perform a `pamtester --verbose rstudio jdoe authenticate` as the user `rstudio-server` I get authentication successful.

But still not able to login to RStudio.

Looking into /var/lof/auth.log I can see that some lines:

```
PAM unable to dlopen(pam_permit.so#015): /lib/security/pam_permit.so#015: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
PAM adding faulty module: pam_permit.so#015
PAM unable to dlopen(pam_deny.so#015): /lib/security/pam_deny.so#015: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
PAM adding faulty module: pam_deny.so#015
```

This happens when I insert a **valid** user (with both the right or a wrong password).

Only if I insert a fake user at login screen I get an additional line `pam_pwdfile(rstudio:auth): user not found in password database`.

I'm totally puzzled why these files are not found: they are not `/lib/security` but in `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/` actually.

Is it because of these missing files I cannot login?

Comment: I should add that from pamtester I get a confirmation message in /var/log/auth if the password matches or if it is wrong. This is not the cae from RStudio login, where I get no debug messages at all!